# Why is code in that is only supposed to be accessible to one target failing to compile for a different target?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cross-platform, target, tvos

I'm having a weird issue. I'm trying to merge two projects (one iOS and one tvOS, both with a mix of objective-c and Swift) into a new single xcode project so that going forward they can share code.

I created a new project, created an iOS target and tvOS target, and brought all of the iOS code over, pretty quickly it was compiling fine for the iOS target. When bringing all of the code from the previous iOS project over I set all of the files to only be accessible to the iOS target.

Then I did the same with the tvOS code, once again only setting the files to be accessible to the tvOS target.

So because both of these code bases are very similar there are a lot of duplicated classes, but that over time have slightly diverged. Eventually my goal is to unify these, but for now I just need to get all the code in the same place. So I have classes with the same name, I was hoping that just having files only accessible to the relevant target would solve this problem for me, but it only kind of does.

After migrating all of the code, the iOS target (which I got working before starting with the tvOS code) still compiles, however, the tvOS target doesn't. It fails on errors that should only be accessible to the iOS target, because the classnames and method are already used ('Duplicate interface definition for class' and similar errors).

So I really don't understand what's happening here -
Why does the the tvOS target have access to code that is only supposed to be available to the iOS target, but not the other way around? What can I do to fix this? (besides just wrapping all of the code in #if Target_OS_ios).

One other thing, the tvOS target only seems to have access to objective-c files from the iOS target, none of the errors have come up in any of the swift classes. Not sure if that is relevant or not.

Comment: Most likely, you're running into header file search path issues.  That a header is a member of a target has little bearing on whether or not the compiler can find it, unfortunately.    For a file that is failing, preprocess the file and see how the header paths resolve.